# msdeploy delete ASP.NET Temporary files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am using msdeploy to delete web sites using this command

```
msdeploy -verb:delete -dest:apphostconfig="Default Web Site/FOO",computerName="BAR"
```

however this does not delete the files under

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\FOO

Is there an argument for msdeploy to delete these files too?
If that is not the case, is there something else I can use in a Power Shell or batch script from a remote computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the runCommand MSDeploy provider:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:runCommand="net start MyService" -dest:auto
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740(v=ws.10).aspx